# WebRTC: multiple video tracks but just one stream actually plays

Tags: webrtc, chromium, raspberry-pi4

In my app, I send streams from multiple web cameras attached to my Raspberry Pi 4B to remote client.
When I run the sending part on Raspberry, and the client elsewhere, the client only plays the stream from the first device (m=0 in SDP).
`chrome://webrtc-internals` for `inbound-rtp (kind=video, mid=0, ...)` shows that the first track is being send over the network with codec set:

```
Statistics IT01V1705444227
timestamp   04/10/2023, 11:16:41
ssrc    1705444227
kind    video
transportId T01
codecId CIT01_102_level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
[codec] H264 (102, level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f)
jitter
```

whereas the same section for `m=1` lacks codec info:

```
timestamp   04/10/2023, 11:18:39
ssrc    1119765391
kind    video
transportId T01
jitter  0
packetsLost 0
```

Some more related statistics:

[image: Stats graphs for inbound-rtp (m=0)]
[image: Stats graphs for inbound-rtp (m=1)]

On the sending side though, `chrome://webrtc-internals` shows codec info for both tracks:

```
Stats graphs for outbound-rtp (kind=video, mid=0, ssrc=2351521644, [codec]=H264 (102, level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f), id=OT01V2351521644)
```

```
Stats graphs for outbound-rtp (kind=video, mid=1, ssrc=2638827077, [codec]=H264 (102, level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f), id=OT01V2638827077)
```

but graphs for the second one are the same.

I've tried playing with maxBitrate and maxFramerate parameters thinking that high CPU usage might throttle the second stream, but it didn't help?

Can someone please help me to debug the second stream not being sent over the network?

Edit: somehow, the second track gets “readyState=ended” on the sending side.